# Ищу штуку для получения и ввода "с листа" распечаток дампов с проверкой контрольных сумм построчно под linux

Tags: unix

Ищу штуковину, которая позволит вводить с бумаги дампы с подсчётом построчных контрольных сумм. Раньше такие дампы печатались в журналах типа "Радио", выглядят примерно так:

```
B3 F2 65 0D 82 CF 46 99 71 3A 99 53 7C 78 C5 B7 22 DE 61 AF E4 99 A5D255
A6 3D 4E 95 0D 3E C6 01 63 CE BE CE 84 F6 CD D3 54 61 8C F9 5B 94 CF045C
```

где последние три байта — CRC24 данной строки, но может быть и CRC16, и однобайтовая контрольная сумма.

Понятно, что при вводе ручками с бумаги без построчной сверки контрольных сумм искать ошибки ввода практически нереально. Тем более странно, что стандартных юниксовых инструментов, предлагающих такую функциональность, я не обнаружил, хотя маны по od и hexdump почитал довольно внимательно. Думал, что такого рода инструменты должны были писа́ться для операционной системы ещё до написания ассемблера.

Comment: только такие контрольные суммы либо подойдет crc-32 ?

Comment: [тут](http://archive.radio.ru/web/1993/05/022/), другая контрольная сумма.

Comment: даже нашлось [как](http://www.danbigras.ru/RK86/Naladka/CRC.html) примерно это считается

Comment: если формат не был распространён за пределами тесного круга советских радиолюбителей, то такой утилиты может и не быть... как вариант, можно всегда набросать небольшой скриптик на перло-питоне...

Comment: из вопроса не ясно нужно ли именно так как там или не столь важно

Comment: @DaniilLoban лучше всего, конечно, чтобы тип контрольной суммы задавался опциями командной строки

Comment: @Fat-Zer но ведь и для Intel HEX ничего маленького нет, а то уже не совсем советские радиолюбители.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev ну это смотря как посмотреть, [вот](https://github.com/micha2070/intelHex) например, с учетом [спецификации](http://www.interlog.com/~speff/usefulinfo/Hexfrmt.pdf) очень даже есть, другое дело то ли это что нужно Вам

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, гугл говорит, что для верификации/конвертации форматами дампов (в том числе Intel HEX) есть набор утилит [srecord](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/)... он почти наверняка есть в репах... но твоего «простого» формата среди поддерживаемых, похоже, нет...

Comment: Если нужно набирать с листа, то удобнее это делать в Excel/OOCalc. Проверку контрольных сумм можно сделать формулами.

Comment: @AlexAlex спасибо! Я как-то даже не подумал в эту сторону.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На всякий случай, написал небольшое решение на `Cи` которое можно расширять.

- Компиляция:  `gcc viewer_chsum.c -o viewer_chsum`
- Запуск: `./viewer_chsum file_path/file_name` например: `./viewer_chsum test`

пример файла:

```
:10010000214601360121470136007EFE09D21901
:100110002146017E17C20001FF5F160021480119
:10012000194E79234623965778239EDA3F01B2CA
:100130003F0156702B5E712B722B732146013421
:00000001
```

вывод (чек-сумма отделена пробелом):

```
:10010000214601360121470136007EFE09D21901 40
:100110002146017E17C20001FF5F160021480119 28
:10012000194E79234623965778239EDA3F01B2CA A7
:100130003F0156702B5E712B722B732146013421 C7
:00000001 FF
```

За основу подсчета чексуммы взята статья из [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX)

Исходник `viewer_chsum.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int hex_to_dec(char * ch){
  char str[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  return (int)(strchr(str, ch[0])-&str[0]) << 4 | strchr(str, ch[1])-&str[0];
}

unsigned int get_chksm(int s){
  return (unsigned int)(~s + 1) & 0xff;
}

void read(char * file){
  FILE * fp;
  char * line = NULL;
  size_t len = 0;
  ssize_t read;
  int i = 0;
  int sum = 0;

  fp = fopen(file, "r");
  if (fp == NULL){
    printf("file \"%s\" not found\n", file) ;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }  
  while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
    i = sum = 0;
    for (i = 3; i < strlen(line); i += 2){ // skip :dd
      sum += hex_to_dec(&line[i]);
    }
    line[(int)strcspn(line, "\r\n")] = 0; // remove new line
    printf("%s %X\n",  line , get_chksm(sum)) ;
  }

  fclose(fp);
  if (line)
    free(line);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc < 2) {
    printf("%s\n", "need an INTEL HEX file as argument");
    return 0;
  }
  read(argv[1]);
  return 0;
}
```